# Apache POI - Excel - File->Passwords->"Read-only recommended" (How to disable)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, readonly-attribute

I have several xlsx files that have the "read-only recommended" flag set.

- Is there a POI 5.x method available to disable this checkbox?

[image: File Passwords]

I looked through [POI XML Properties](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/5.0/org/apache/poi/ooxml/POIXMLProperties.html) with no luck.

Comment: Is there only the checkbox set without passwords?

Comment: Yes - that is correct - just the checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Office Open XML`-Excel files the setting "read only recommended" is stored in `/xl/workbook.xml` as an attribute in a `fileSharing` XML-element.

```
...
<fileSharing readOnlyRecommended="1"/>
...
```

This can be set or unset using `apache poi` only using the low level `org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.*`-classes.

Complete example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.*;

import java.io.*;

class ExcelRemoveReadOnlyRecommended  {

 static void removeReadOnlyRecommended(XSSFWorkbook workbook) {    
  CTWorkbook ctWorkbook = workbook.getCTWorkbook();
  CTFileSharing ctfilesharing = ctWorkbook.getFileSharing();
  if (ctfilesharing != null) {
   ctfilesharing.setReadOnlyRecommended(false);
  }
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     
  String sourceFilePath = "./sourceFile.xlsx";
  String resultFilePath = "./resultFile.xlsx";
    
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(sourceFilePath));
  
  if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
   removeReadOnlyRecommended((XSSFWorkbook)workbook);
  }

  OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(resultFilePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

If the `sourceFile.xlsx` has set that option, but without passwords, then after running that code the `resultFile.xlsx` has not set that option anymore.

If passwords are set too, then decryption is needed at first and the password in `fileSharing` needs to be unset too. Of course then at least the decryption-password needs to be known.

Comment: Excellent - that is exactly what I have been looking for.